# How to use logical OR in SPARQL regex()?

Tags: python, regex, filter, sparql

I'm using this line in a SPARQL query in my python program:

```
FILTER regex(?name, "%s", "i" )
```

(where `%s` is the search text entered by the user)

I want this to match if either `?name` or `?featurename` contains `%s`, but I can't seem to find any documentation or tutorial for using regex(). I tried a couple things that seemed reasonable:

```
FILTER regex((?name | ?featurename), "%s", "i" )
FILTER regex((?name || ?featurename), "%s", "i" )
FILTER regex((?name OR ?featurename), "%s", "i" )
FILTER regex((?name, ?featurename), "%s", "i" )
```

and each of those without the `()`

```
FILTER regex(?name, "%s", "i" ) || regex(?featurename, "%s", "i" )
```

What's the right way to do this?
Thanks

UPDATE: Using UNION works. But I figured out that it also works if you just repeat the regex() part like so:

```
FILTER (regex(?name, "%s", "i") || regex(?featurename, "%s", "i" ))
```

Both solutions seem a little messy in that you have to use a 2-element tuple with copies of the same string to fill in both `%s`s.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT ?thing
WHERE {
  { 
    ?thing x:name ?name .
    FILTER regex(?name, "%s", "i" )
  } UNION {
    ?thing x:featurename ?name .
    FILTER regex(?featurename, "%s", "i" )
  }
}
```